# Como escolher um vídeo da galeria para ser ser padrão e ser reproduzido sempre?

Tags: android, vídeo, sharedpreferences

Estou trabalhando em um programa, que seja interativo com os usuários.

Com isso, o usuário pode escolher imagem ou tirar uma foto e substituir por aquela que estava no `ImageView`.

Quando clica no `ImageView`, reproduz-se um vídeo referente aquela imagem.

Para fixação da imagem (escolhida pelo usuário) no meu `ImageView` eu utilizei `SharedPreferences`, e funcionou.

Porém para fixar um vídeo em uma determinada `ImageView` para que sempre clicar nela, reproduza o vídeo, não estou obtendo o mesmo êxito.

Alguém sabe como poderia fazer?

Comment: Wolney, seria mais fácil ajudá-lo se colocasse o código que já tentou.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está percetível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).